# segment tree for adding a array with single index updates

Tags: python, tree

I have written a program to sum up a value between a range using segment tree and this tree also supports single index updates. 
I am wondering if I have followed all the python rules for names and other pythonic nuances. Please let me know your comments.

Tree has below functions:

1. Modify - helps in modifying the individual array elements.
2. Query - given a range this function will return the sum of all the elements in the range. Such as given [3, 7) will sum up index 3 to 6 excluding 7.

   ```
   def next_power_2(n):
       n -= 1
       n |= n >> 1
       n |= n >> 2
       n |= n >> 4
       n |= n >> 8
       n |= n >> 16
       n += 1
       return n

   class segment_tree(object):
       def __init__(self, n, data):
           self.total_elements = n
           self.n = next_power_2(n) #segment tree is always balanced binary tree
           self.tree = [0] * self.n + data + [0] * (self.n - n) 

       def build(self):
           for i in range(self.n-1, 0, -1):
               self.tree[i] = self.tree[2*i] + self.tree[2*i+1]

       def modify(self, pos, val):
           if pos < 0 or pos >= self.total_elements:
               print("check your inputs")
               return -1
           pos = pos + self.n
           self.tree[pos] = val
           while pos/2 > 0:
               self.tree[pos/2] = self.tree[pos] + self.tree[pos^1]
               pos = pos/2

       def query(self, left, right):
           if left > self.total_elements or left < 0:
               print("check your inputs")
               return -1
           if right > self.total_elements or right < 0:
               print("check your inputs")
               return -1
           left = self.n + left
           right = self.n + right
           s = 0
           while left < right:
               if left&1:
                   s += self.tree[left]
                   left += 1
               if right&1:
                   right -= 1
                   s += self.tree[right]
               left /= 2
               right /= 2
           return s

       def __repr__(self):
           return " ".join(str(i) for i in self.tree)

   print("enter the number of elements")
   n = int(raw_input())
   print("enter the elements as space seperated integer values")
   data = [int(i) for i in raw_input().split()]
   st = segment_tree(n, data)
   st.build()
   print("enter the position and value which you want to modify as space seperated integer values")
   pos, val = map(int, raw_input().split())
   print("pos", pos, "value", val)
   st.modify(pos, val)
   print("enter the left and right range as space seperated integer values")
   left, right = map(int, raw_input().split())
   print("left", left, "right", right)
   print("sum for the given range is:", st.query(left, right))
   print(st)
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I'd implement `next_power_2` like this, using [`int.bit_length`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length):

```
def next_power_2(n):
    "If n > 0, return smallest power of 2 greater than or equal to n."
    return 1 << (n - 1).bit_length()
```

This is more than twice as fast as than the version in the post, and it works for arbitrarily large integers.

Comment: Thanks but i was wondering if i can get some comments about my python skills.